# save leaflet map tiles to use offline

Tags: javascript, wordpress, leaflet, pouchdb

I'm using leaflet to render a map inside a wordpress powered app. I'm looking for a way to store the map tiles inside the localstorage of the user device, this because I want to avoid that the tiles are downloaded everytime. I want to use pouchDB or similar to save the data on the devices, but I' not sure about this. 
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: PouchDB would be overkill for your requirements - you might find a better solution with [dexie.js](https://dexie.org/).  PouchDB is a good choice when requirements call for local -> remote database replication.

Comment: Ok, I will read about it, but for the tiles, how I save them? This is what I want to understand mainly

Comment: https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.TileLayer.PouchDBCached , although using service workers feels like a cleaner way (e.g. as in https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/cuantotardamiautobus/blob/master/src/madrid/service-worker.js )

Comment: @IvanSanchez, I saw your link to service workers, I never used it so I need to understand how to implement with leaflet and the osm tiles provided by wikimedia. Thanks for the suggestion